# How can I set up my Ruby-on-Rails application to run one of the popular Javascript unit testing frameworks with Minitest?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest

I've managed to get [Capybara](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara) set up with Minitest for Javascript-supported feature and integration tests. I'd also like to set up a Javascript unit testing framework.

It looks like the popular gems — [Jasmine](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails), [Teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon), [Konacha](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha) — all target RSpec. And Google hasn't turned up much literature on the subject.

Is there a gem that supports Javascript unit testing for Minitest? Or is there another simple way to integrate Javascript unit tests into my app's test suite?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote up an answer about using selenium-webdriver to test JavaScript features, however, I realize that this may not be exactly what you're looking for, as I'm not familiar with JavaScript frameworks. My answer is about using Capybara to open a browser where it can access JavaScript. Would this be helpful to you, do you think?

Comment: @wendybeth That sounds like the part I got running with [minitest-rails-capybara](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara) and the webkit driver. I'm looking here for something more like [Teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon).